# How to load a rest store with ID in Sencha Touch 2.4.2?

Tags: rest, store, mode, senchatouch-2.4

Here within a controller I create a rest store:

```
this.somePerson = Ext.create('Ilhan.store.Human', {
    model: 'Ilhan.model.Human',
    autoLoad: false
});
this.somePerson(123);
```

But it doesn't load the person with id 123 even though I have set idProperty in the model. It loadds all the humans.

This one loads can retrieve the human with ID 123.

```
Ext.ModelManager.getModel('Ilhan.model.Human').load(record.data.ID, {
    success: function(recordd) {
        someHuman = recordd;
    }
});
```

It gets the human with ID 123 but then someHuman is not a store. Thus `someHuman.sync()` doesn't work, it says that `sync()` is not defined. Or if I use `someHuman.save()` it `PUT`s all the data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You must look at [findBy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findBy).

example (not tested):

```
var indexOfHuman123 = this.somePerson.findBy( function(recordTest){
    if( recordTest.get('id') == 123 )
        return true;

    return false;
});
var modelOfHuman123;
if( indexOfHuman123 != -1 )
    modelOfHuman123 = this.somePerson.getAt(indexOfHuman123);
```